# How do I install an rwhois server?

Tags: whois

I want to run an [rwhois](https://www.arin.net/resources/request/reassignments_rwhois.html) server as an ISP, to manage customers' WHOIS information. [ARIN's implementation](http://web.archive.org/web/20160610093040/http://projects.arin.net/rwhois/) seems to be abandoned or lost. Is that still the server to run? Are there updated instructions or support available anywhere?

Comment: The rwhois protocol hasn't really changed in nearly 20 years. That rwhois clients and servers were last updated long ago should not surprise you; they have been trying to get rid of whois for quite a while. The protocol's replacement is RDAP, for which you can find current software.